# C# Problema al cargar datos desde un archivo .xls

Tags: c#, oledb

Buen día, mi inconveniente es al cargar los datos desde un archivo exel, al momento de mostrarlos me los deja en blanco unos campos.

Caso 1.

En el exel estan los datos que quiero

[image: Datos en el Exel]

Y esto es lo que se ve al cargar el exel, solo me muestra los campos con numero y no los que tienen letras y números, el la columna "puesto".

[image: Datos mostrados en el sistema]

Caso 2.

[image: Datos en el Exel]

y lo que me muestra en sistema es esto, ahora inverso, me muestra los campos de letras y números, pero no de solo números, en la columna posiciones, lo mismo pasa con los teléfonos y demás columnas.

[image: Datos mostrados en el sistema]

El código que uso para que me genere el DataTable para manipular la informacion

```
 public static DataTable GetDataExcel(string SourcePath, string sheetName)
    {
        try
        {
            string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                    "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;';" +
                    "Data Source =" + SourcePath;
            //"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; "+
            //"Data Source = " + fileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";  

            using (OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", sheetName);
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                da.Fill(dt);

                return dt;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Me gustaría que me cargara todos los datos tal cual salen en el Exel, sin excepción, yo ya me encargaría de formatearlos por código, *Los tres primeros campos se me paso capturarlos en la foto del exel*, se nota mas claro el ejemplo en la columna puesto.

*Espero que se vean las imágenes, en mi trabajo al parecer tienen bloqueado el dominio "imgur.com".

Comment: pero cual es la duda, te refieres a no mostrar las columnas ocultas? y cual es la duda en tu codigo?

Comment: de donde obtienes los datos de los 3 primeros campos ? porque el `nombre` y `apellido` materno y paterno no los veo como columnas del excel

Comment: Ya actualice, en resumen, la columna se restringe, o son números o son texto, me borra la información del contrario, y me gustaría que mostrara todo, sin importar que fuera texto o número.

Answer (score 0):

Usa esta cadena de conexión:

```
string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                        "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";"+
                        "Data Source =" + SourcePath + ";";
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Usando este metodo paso todos los datos del excel a un datagridview, lo puedes modoficar a tu gusto.
Le paso mediante un textbox la ruta donde esta ubicado el excel y el nombre de la Hoja donde esta la informacion.

```
 private void btnOpendialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog uploadfile = new OpenFileDialog();
        if(uploadfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textLink.Text = uploadfile.FileName;
            ExcelGridview(textNamesheet.Text);
        }
    }
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    public void ExcelGridview(string hoja)
    {
        try
        {
            string cadena = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"Data Source=" + textLink.Text + ";" + @"Extended Properties=" + '"' + "Excel 8.0;HDR=YES" + '"';

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(cadena);
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM ["+hoja+"$]";

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, con);



            da.Fill(ds);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```